# django allauth social accounts not showing in template

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm on django 1.8 and django all auth, the latest.

I've installed django-allauth following the official docs. Have migrated database.

In the account/login.html template file, there's the part which says

```
{% if socialaccount.providers  %}
<p>{% blocktrans with site.name as site_name %}Please sign in with one
of your existing third party accounts. Or, <a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a>
for a {{site_name}} account and sign in below:{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<div class="socialaccount_ballot">

  <ul class="socialaccount_providers">
    {% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" with process="login" %}
  </ul>

  <div class="login-or">{% trans 'or' %}</div>

</div>

{% include "socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html" %}

{% else %}
....
```

Although I have added a social app, it doesn't seem to see it and the logic test fails in the template, thus, the social account part not showing.

I explicitly added

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url "google" process="connect" %}">Connect a Twitter account</a>
```

And it could recognize the google app I've added to the social app. As a control, I deleted the social app, and the explicit provider login url I added resulted in a DoesNotExist exception

Have I not done something right, or its just that django-allauth isn't compatible with 1.8 django fully yet?

Comment: check if you `socialaccount ` is provided by the view or the context processor.

Comment: View? You mean settings.py? I have the context set in the settings.py and have loaded the socialaccount tag in templates already.

Comment: Do you get anything when you try printing out `{{ socialaccount.providers }}`?

Comment: @onyeka gives me nothing. However, calling the socialaccount url directly works.

Comment: @onyeka I think the issue got fixed after the django 1.8 allauth compatible update rolled out